# Group by to concatenate strings without collect_list/collect_set - Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|MeteVarID                           |Conc                          |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|9d71445e-ee5d-4d37-bfb7-02f6e6eacd9d|Friday 0 0.9604490986400536   |
|9d71445e-ee5d-4d37-bfb7-02f6e6eacd9d|Friday 1 0.8109076852795446   |
|9d71445e-ee5d-4d37-bfb7-02f6e6eacd9d|Friday 2 0.7282039568471731   |
|9d71445e-ee5d-4d37-bfb7-02f6e6eacd9d|Friday 3 0.5335418350493728   |
```

And I would like to group by `MeteVarID` and concatenate the strings. The final dataframe should be like:

```
9d71445e-ee5d-4d37-bfb7-02f6e6eacd9d | Friday 0 0.9604490986400536, Friday 1 0.8109076852795446, etc.
```

Comment: Did you try with `concat_ws` ?

Comment: @philantrovert with concat_ws I should use collect_list and my SPARK version doesn't support that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the plain ol' RDD API and switch back to dataframe.

```
df.rdd
  .map( c=> (c.getAs[String]("MeteVarID")  , c.getAs[String]("Conc") ) )
  .reduceByKey( _ +", "+ _)
  .toDF("MeteVarID", "Conc")
  .show(false)

+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|MeteVarID                           |Conc                                                                                                              |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|9d71445e-ee5d-4d37-bfb7-02f6e6eacd9d|Friday 0 0.9604490986400536, Friday 1 0.8109076852795446, Friday 2 0.7282039568471731, Friday 3 0.5335418350493728|
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```